# Software for Passport ID OCR

Tags: open-source, ocr, computer-vision

Can you recommend open source software for recognizing passport numbers in photographs? Or some other tool that can be used to solve this problem. We have data on which we can train software. Something the same as Rasa for chat bots.

Comment: What OS should the software run on? What is your price tag (i.e. how much you'd willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions)? Apart from recognizing, what should the software do if it identified such a number – beep? flash the screen? Export the number, map it in some database, …?

Comment: All passports, or just those from a given county?

Comment: We will be using Ubuntu.To be precise, I'm rather looking for a framework that can be trained on passport photos. For example, some kind of Python framework.But at the same time, something more off-the-shelf like Rasa rather than Tesseract OCR.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying: Someone answered with a non-open source tool, arguing that it was valid because you wrote "some other tool". Would you mind making that aspect of your question more explicit? Thanks!